# Dual boot from separate HDDs

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, multi-boot, fedora

What I want to do is create a machine where in my primary HDD, in this case an SSD there is Windows and where a second HDD there is Fedora.
I know almost anything, but I really wanted to be sure before proceeding.
If I install Windows as first OS then when I install fedora on the second HDD I just have to install on **/dev/sdb** and not to mess around Windows SSD I have to locate ***GRUB*** in the second HDD, too.
By doing this I should be able to have 2 different Os in two separate HDD, right?
Did I miss something? Remember that I do not want to harm in any way the content in Windows... It mustn't be touched.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that will work, I have my gaming PC setup like this, one SSD for Windows, an old SSD I have fedora installed on. The only issue is you cannot choose an OS without going in to the BIOS to override to a certain boot device (that is on some BIOSes you can pick a boot device by pressing enter/esc/F1-10 at boot, then pick the disc you want to boot from) as far as I know you can't have a grub boot loader installed on one device and have one of the options point to the other disc, although this may be possible, it doesn't interest me as I only boot to fedora occasionally.

When installing Fedora it should be very obvious which disk is which (the disk make/model will show up for one)

Comment: kinda. You could always chainload windows from fedora. When I did this, I *unplugged* my windows hard drive just to be safe - grub didn't pick up windows till the next time it was updated.

Comment: Yeah I've considered doing that briefly, but I didn't see much point, I quite like how quickly it boots right now and only very rarely want to boot in to fedora. Thanks though!